# I can't install Jupyter and Matplotlib in my anaconda env

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have an environment of Anaconda (apart of root) and I'm trying to install this two libraries with no success. I tried:

- Install libraries by the environment tools of Anaconda Navigator with
  'Multiple Errors Encountered.' error. Could I get more info about it? The options that I saw didn't say anything more.
- > 'Multiple Errors Encountered.'
- Install Jupyter with the install option of the apps of Anaconda Navigator with the same error too
- > 'Multiple Errors Encountered.'
- Install with `conda install jupyter` and `conda install matplotlib` in the console and cd where the environment is located. The console
  made its process and it said that both libraries were already
  installed. I check it in the libraries list of Anaconda Navigator and
  it doesn't appear.
- > (base) C:\Users...>cd C:\Users\Alvaro\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow
  >
  > (base) C:\Users...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow>conda install
  >   matplotlib Solving environment: done
  >
  > ## All requested packages already installed.
  >
  > (base) C:\Users\Alvaro\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow>conda install jupyter
  >   Solving environment: done
  >
  > ## All requested packages already installed.
- Install with `pip install jupyter` and `pip install matplotlib` with the similar result than conda install option.

  - > (base) C:\Users\Alvaro\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow>pip install jupyter Requirement already satisfied: jupyter in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.0.0) Requirement
    >   already satisfied: notebook in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter) (5.5.0)
    >   Requirement already satisfied: qtconsole in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter) (4.3.1)
    >   Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-console in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter) (5.2.0)
    >   Requirement already satisfied: nbconvert in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter) (5.3.1)
    >   Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter) (4.8.2)
    >   Requirement already satisfied: ipywidgets in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from jupyter) (7.2.1)
    >   Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=5.2.0 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
    >   (5.2.3) Requirement already satisfied: nbformat in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
    >   (4.4.0) Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
    >   (0.2.0) Requirement already satisfied: Send2Trash in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
    >   (1.5.0) Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2.1 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
    >   (4.3.2) Requirement already satisfied: terminado>=0.8.1 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
    >   (0.8.1) Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
    >   (2.10) Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core>=4.4.0 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
    >   (4.4.0) Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
    >   (5.0.2) Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from notebook->jupyter)
    >   (17.0.0) Requirement already satisfied: ipython in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   jupyter-console->jupyter) (6.4.0) Requirement already satisfied:
    >   prompt_toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   jupyter-console->jupyter) (1.0.15) Requirement already satisfied:
    >   pygments in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   jupyter-console->jupyter) (2.2.0) Requirement already satisfied:
    >   mistune>=0.7.4 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   nbconvert->jupyter) (0.8.3) Requirement already satisfied:
    >   entrypoints>=0.2.2 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
    >   (from nbconvert->jupyter) (0.2.3) Requirement already satisfied:
    >   bleach in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   nbconvert->jupyter) (2.1.3) Requirement already satisfied:
    >   pandocfilters>=1.4.1 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
    >   (from nbconvert->jupyter) (1.4.2) Requirement already satisfied:
    >   testpath in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   nbconvert->jupyter) (0.3.1) Requirement already satisfied:
    >   widgetsnbextension~=3.2.0 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
    >   (3.2.1) Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   jupyter-client>=5.2.0->notebook->jupyter) (2.7.3) Requirement already
    >   satisfied: jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   nbformat->notebook->jupyter) (2.6.0) Requirement already satisfied:
    >   six in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   traitlets>=4.2.1->notebook->jupyter) (1.11.0) Requirement already
    >   satisfied: decorator in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
    >   (from traitlets>=4.2.1->notebook->jupyter) (4.3.0) Requirement already
    >   satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   jinja2->notebook->jupyter) (1.0) Requirement already satisfied:
    >   setuptools>=18.5 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter) (39.1.0) Requirement already
    >   satisfied: simplegeneric>0.8 in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter) (0.8.1) Requirement already
    >   satisfied: backcall in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
    >   (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter) (0.1.0) Requirement already
    >   satisfied: pickleshare in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
    >   (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter) (0.7.4) Requirement already
    >   satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter) (0.3.9) Requirement already
    >   satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
    >   (from ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter) (0.12.0) Requirement already
    >   satisfied: wcwidth in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
    >   (from prompt_toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter) (0.1.7)
    >   Requirement already satisfied:
    >   html5lib!=1.0b1,!=1.0b2,!=1.0b3,!=1.0b4,!=1.0b5,!=1.0b6,!=1.0b7,!=1.0b8,>=0.99999999pre in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   bleach->nbconvert->jupyter) (1.0.1) Requirement already satisfied:
    >   parso>=0.2.0 in c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   jedi>=0.10->ipython->jupyter-console->jupyter) (0.2.0) Requirement
    >   already satisfied: webencodings in
    >   c:\users\alvaro\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from
    >   html5lib!=1.0b1,!=1.0b2,!=1.0b3,!=1.0b4,!=1.0b5,!=1.0b6,!=1.0b7,!=1.0b8,>=0.99999999pre->bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
    >   (0.5.1) distributed 1.21.8 requires msgpack, which is not installed.
    >   You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
    >   You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade
    >   pip' command.
- Install with PyCharm, with the libraries installation function of the interpreter settings of it. It gets also an error to install:
- > Install packages failed: Installing packages: error occurred.
  >   Details...

I tried to install other libraries with success (sympy, for example), but I didn't achieve it with Jupyter and Matplotlib.

The root environment has this libraries, but I don't know if I could import from there.
How I should to proceed?

Thank you very much

Comment: What is the **ERROR**

Comment: What does "The root environment has this libraries, but I don't know if I could import from there." mean? If those packages are installed, what problem is there using them?

Comment: These libraries are in the root environment, but I have created another one to work with Tensorflow. I don't know if I can import from root env to TF env and how. Whatever, I would like to install Jupyter and Matplotlib in the TF env.

Comment: @AMGMNPLK  the Pycharm failure is another question

Comment: @AMGMNPLK Please activate your tensorflow environment and type `conda list`  to let us know all the packages in the environment . After that check whether Jupyter isis really installed there.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post explains how to install jupyter into a virtualenv (Disclaimer: I didn't come up with it myself):
http://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/

In summary:

```
$ python -m venv projectname
$ source projectname/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip install ipykernel
(venv) $ ipython kernel install --user --name=projectname
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, I tried, but without the first line, because I already have a venv. The second line doesn't work for me, it said that source is not found as a command. The las two didn't installed the Jupyter Notebook. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have got it probably.

TLDR: You probably installed jupyter in your base (or root in your language) environment.
I have copied over a small snippet of your messages.

```sh
Install with conda install jupyter and conda install matplotlib in the console and cd where the environment is located. The console made its process and it said that both libraries were already installed. I check it in the libraries list of Anaconda Navigator and it doesn't appear.
(base) C:\Users...>cd C:\Users\Alvaro\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow

(base) C:\Users...\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow>conda install matplotlib Solving environment: done

All requested packages are already installed.
(base) C:\Users\Alvaro\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow>conda install jupyter Solving environment: done
```

Now I am assuming that the above packages really got installed properly.

> Why I am doubtful.`Solving environment: done` is not the last line after a package gets installed.

If you see the first line of each of these messages they all begin with `base`. This indicates that the packages got installed in the `base` environment, not your `TensorFlow environment.

So you really won't find them in your `TensorFlow environment.

It would help if you also answer my questions in the comments below the question.